# java 8 streams unwind or emit lists to get single values

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a map like so:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> map
```

Now I want do take all the list entries from the map values and use them as key in another map.

```
Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .fiter(somefilter -> true)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
      k -> k.getValue(), // I want to have every single value as key
      v -> v.getKey());
```

Is there a way to "unwind" arrays in Java 8 streams? In MongoDB I would write something like this:

```
Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .fiter(somefilter -> true)
  .unwind(entry -> entry.getValue())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
      k -> k.getValue(), 
      v -> v.getKey());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to create streams of pairs of value/key (for example with an array) and flat map them for collection:

```
 Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet().stream()
         .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> new String[] { s, e.getKey() }))
         .collect(toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));
```

The String array looks a bit hacky though...

Comment: yes this works! cool thanks. Instead of the "hackisch" string array, you could use `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String > (s, e.getKey()))`